# How many Cycles are needed to transfer a block of 32 bytes?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, bus

The question is:

A wide bus configuration has the following parameters:

- Number of cycles to send the address
- Number of cycles for a bus transfer = 2 cycles
- Memory Access = 30 cycles

How many cycles are need to transfer a block of 32 bytes?

So, since it's a wide bus configuration I assumed that the bus transfer cycle will be done over one iteration and same for memory access

Which means that I got 30 + 2 cycles = 32

However I can't make sense of the size of the bus and its impact. I can't understand how i can calculate the the number of cycles left from it

Comment: You left out some critical details, like the width of the bus (bytes per transfer).  I assume it's not 32 bytes wide, but works in burst transfers where you send the address once, and every 2 cycles after that, you get back n bytes of data?  Like how an SDRAM burst read or write command works?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory

Comment: Sadly that was all provided in the question
There is no missing info